# Conversion from buffer of bytes to string then back to bytes in NodeJS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, encoding

Like the title states, I am just trying to encode some bytes in a string, then decode them back to bytes. The conversion of a Uint8 array of bytes to string then back to array does not happen perfectly. I am just wondering what encoding I should use in the conversion to make it happen correctly.

I try this as a dummy example:

```
  var bytes = serializeToBinary(); // giving me bytes 
  console.log('bytes type:'+ Object.prototype.toString.call(bytes));
  console.log('bytes length:'+ bytes.length);

  var bytesStr = bytes.toString('base64'); // gives me a string that looks like '45,80,114,98,97,68,111'
  console.log('bytesStr length:'+ bytesStr.length);
  console.log('bytesStr type:'+ Object.prototype.toString.call(bytesStr));

  var decodedbytesStr = Buffer.from(bytesStr, 'base64');
  console.log('decodedbytesStr type:'+ Object.prototype.toString.call(decodedbytesStr));
  console.log('decodedbytesStr length:'+ decoded.length);
```

Output:

```
bytes type:[object Uint8Array]
bytes length:4235
bytesStr type:[object String]
bytesStr length:14161
decodedbytesStr type:[object Uint8Array]
decodedbytesStr length:7445
```

Shouldn't decodedbytesStr length and bytes length be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypedArray` does not support `.toString('base64')`. The `base64` argument is ignored, and you simply get a string representation of the array's values, separated by commas. This is **not** a base64 string, so `Buffer.from(bytesStr, 'base64')` is not processing it correctly.

You want to call `.toString('base64')` on a `Buffer` instead. When creating `bytesStr`, simply build a `Buffer` from your `Uint8Array` first:

```
var bytesStr = Buffer.from(bytes).toString('base64');
```

Comment: @ah997n I have made far stupider mistakes myself! `:)` You're welcome.